# Show COD Payment Method as Disable in Checkout if product with Some attribute in the cart

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3

I have to display COD payment method but as disabled in payment step if a product with Some attribute in the cart.

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/KAiB40qad]

Please help me.